# Axis tick labelling

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The x axis of my line graph represents money. Is there any way to append a € symbol to the beginning of each tick?

At the moment they are just values 2000000, 250000, 300000....

I would like them to display €2000000, €250000, €300000....

I tried adding the € to my .CSV file but it caused an error when I tried to call the data to make my axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `tickFormat` function:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_tickFormat

For example:

```
axis.tickFormat( function(d) { return "€" + d } );
```

Also consider using [d3.format](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#wiki-d3_format) to group your numbers by with commas/periods, etc.