# format axis tick labels

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, legend

I'm using a map chart where area's are colored based on a percentage. The legend shows a mapping between the colors and their percentages. But the legend only shows numbers, not percentages. It should be obvious that these numbers are percentages. So there should be a % symbol after each number or a % symbol at the top of the chart.

It seems there is such a thing as [chart tick formatting](http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/xaxis-tick-format-with-tickpositions-t23924/) but I cannot find a way to change it. Maybe this could be done with [stacklabels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels) I would expect something [like this with d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009500/axis-tick-labelling). I tried this with highCharts, but it seems to ignore these properties.

I also tried changing the format properties of several other objects. Changing it on the legend object get's you closest, but it's only one text on the wrong position.

Edit: something that complicates this is that I don't think the chart has an x or y-axis. Instead there's a colorAxis object. Maybe it's possible to add text with CSS3 with the itemStyle property.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: you want the percent sign in the legend or in the x axis label?

Comment: @void No JsFiddle, either position would be fine. I think the x axis label would be better and easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty simple, all you need to do is use [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter)

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
       return this.value+"%";
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks, had not found the labels object. It works :) I used  format: '{value} %'