# D3 Line chart - display value label on Y axis tick and a not scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to print a label on the Y axis instead of a scaled tick range. Here is my dataset, where I want wish to print data.values[i].label on the Y axis.

```
var data = [
  {
    name: "USA",
    values: [
      {date: "2000", price: "500", label: "High"},
      {date: "2001", price: "400", label: "High"},
      {date: "2002", price: "300", label: "Medium"},
      {date: "2003", price: "200", label: "Medium"},
      {date: "2004", price: "100", label: "Low"},
      {date: "2005", price: "200", label: "Medium"}
    ]
  }
];
```

I figured I need to do something on line 157 like was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009500/axis-tick-labelling) but I would need to pass the values[i] in, and not just the price. Something like

```
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat( function(d) { return d.label } );
```

Some guidance would be appreciated. 
I've been testing it on codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jdaWmR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that is helpfull for you

```
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5).tickFormat( function(d, i) { return data[0].values[i].label;  } );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might be able to make this answer better by explaining what this code does and why it works; answers consisting of just code tend to be discouraged.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!